# Coordinate free proof that det is algebraic

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, lie-groups

If V is a vector space of dimension N, and $f\colon V \to V$ is an endomorphism, one defines its determinant to be the scalar corresponding to the induced map $\wedge^N V \to \wedge^N V$.

I like this definition, but I can't really say I know how to work with it. For example, how do you prove that det is an algebraic map? I'd like to show that GL(V) is a variety, without picking a basis for V.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, det is a map End(V) $\to$ End($\wedge^N V$) = k, where k is the base field. This map is far from being linear, in fact by picking a basis for V one can look up in any textbook that it is a polynomial of degree N in the entries of the corresponding matrix, i.e. an element of Sym$^N$End(V)$^*$. So the question boils down to identifying det as an element of SymEnd(V)$^*$ = SymEnd(V$^*$).

Comment: This looks fascinating, but what does it mean? What is $\wedge^NV$?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs [you can start here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra)

Comment: Do you mean to show that the *non-invertible* matrices form a variety?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom either statement would suffice: the variety {det = 0} is the complement of the Zariski open GL. I just don't know a coordinate-free way of doing it.

Comment: Aren't multilinear maps algebraic?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard I am 100% sure the answer is not much deeper than what you just said, I just don't know how to make it precise.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard But is the determinant really a multilinear map ? I mean, as a map from $V^n\rightarrow k$ it certainly is, but then itdepends on the choice of a basis and the OP want to avoid that. But as a map $\operatorname{End}(V)\rightarrow k$, it is not multilinear. I believe that the question is somehow identify the determinant as an element in $S^N\operatorname{End}(V)^*$ without using a basis. (But maybe I misinterpreted something...)

Comment: I mean, you can view det as a multilinear map $V^N \to \wedge^N V$, this does not depend on a basis or orientation. But, yeah, that's how far I get.

Comment: @Roland Yes. I'd be happy with showing that the hypersurface $Z \subset$ End(V)  defined by {det=0} is a Zariski closed subset. This amounts to showing det is algebraic, i.e. identifying it as an element of the coordinate ring of End(V), which is Sym $End(V)^*$, which I guess may be identified with Sym End($V^*$).

Comment: @Roland - You're right, I was sloppy. It seems to me it suffices to check that the natural map $\operatorname{End}(V)\to\operatorname{End}(\bigwedge^nV)$ is polynomial. (Here $n:=\dim V$.)

Comment: @MatthiasVolkov dumb question, but is there a "coordinate-free" definition of an algebraic function?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If $V$ is a vector space, an algebraic function on $V$ is a element of the symmetric algebra $\operatorname{Sym}V^*$.

Comment: @Roland Neat!  Thanks

Comment: @Roland - Also, the natural object to define is the determinant of an endomorphism of a free module $F$ of finite rank over a commutative ring. To define it we must use the assumption that $F$ has a finite basis. Perhaps it's not reasonable a coordinate-free definition. Perhaps it's more reasonable to expect a definition by choosing a basis and showing that the choice doesn't matter...

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard I'm not sure. Let M be a module over any commutative ring R. The exterior powers $\wedge^k M$ are well defined for any k. There is a map End(M) $\to$ End($\wedge^k M)$. In the special case that $M$ is projective of rank n, the map End(M) $\to$ End($\wedge^n M$) is the determinant. My guess is that End(M) $\to$ End($\wedge^k M)$ is algebraic for any k.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard OK, maybe I should retract my last comment. I thought about the trace of a linear map. Now trace is truly not always defined. Indeed, trace is really a map $V^* \otimes V \to k$. Then one notices the inclusion $V^* \otimes V \to$End(V) and defines the trace on its image (which coincides with the whole thing when V has finite dimension). But I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: @MatthiasVolkov - Thanks for your comments! I find your question very interesting!!! Could you remind me of the definition of an *algebraic* map (say between two finite dimensional spaces)? (Perhaps you gave it and I missed it.) Do you make a distinction between *algebraic* map and *polynomial* map?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Algebraic and polynomial mean the same thing. I think of Sym $V^*$ as the coordinate ring of the vector space V. So a map $V \to W$ is algebraic if it comes from a morphism of k-algebras Sym $W^* \to $ Sym $V^*$.

Comment: This can perhaps be said more precisely. Assume we are working over the complex numbers C. If V is a vector space, then write Fun(V) for the set of functions $V \to C$. We may identify $Sym V^*$ as a subset of Fun(V). Given a map $f\colon V \to W$, we have a "pullback" $f^*\colon Fun(W) \to Fun(V)$ defined by precomposition. Declare $f$ to be algebraic if $f^*$ sends any element of $Sym W^*$ to an element of $Sym V^*$. This has to be the most convoluted way to say that a map $C^n \to C^m$ is polynomial... (but it's coordinate free!)

Comment: @MatthiasVolkov - I think the following is an equivalent way, much more naive and less elegant, but also coordinate-free. Let $K$ be the ground field. Say that $f:V\to K$ (with $V$ a vector space) is *monomial* if it is a product of linear forms, that $f:V\to K$ is *polynomial* if it is a sum of monomial maps, and that $f:V\to W$ (with $W$ a vector space) is *polynomial* if its composition $V\to W\to K$ with any linear form on $W$ is.

Comment: If you cannot come up with a version of the statement that is true for infinite-dimensional vector spaces as well, I would be inclined to believe you can't prove it without picking a basis (or something more or less equivalent to a basis).

Comment: @EricWofsey proving that that the induced map End(V) $\to$ End($\wedge^k V$) is algebraic for any $k$ is independent of the dimension of V. Hence it has a chance of working even in the infinite dimensional case.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier just to give a coordinate-free proof that $GL(V)$ is a variety. The point is that the multiplication map

$$\text{End}(V) \times \text{End}(V) \to \text{End}(V)$$

is an algebraic map (because it's bilinear), and $GL(V)$ is the closed subvariety of $\text{End}(V) \times \text{End}(V)$ given by the inverse image of $\text{id}_V \in \text{End}(V)$ under this map.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about this approach. Very straightforward. I would still like to know how to show det is algebraic though!

Comment: @Matthias: here is a sophisticated way to do it. To say that the determinant, regarded as a map $\text{End}(V) \to k$, is algebraic is the same as saying it can be upgraded to a natural transformation between the functor of points of the corresponding affine schemes. That you can do this basically boils down to the observation that the definition of the determinant makes sense for endomorphisms of finite rank free modules over any commutative ring $R$, in a way that's functorial in $R$. I can say this with more details if desired.

Comment: I understand the functor of points statement, but I don't know how to make it rigorous without picking a basis and knowing a formula for det.

Comment: @Matthias: there are some limits to what can be done here. First, it's a little unclear what "dimension $N$" means if it doesn't mean "has a basis of size $N$" (although there are possible responses here, e.g. length). Second, and relatedly, it's a little unclear how to go about showing that $\Lambda^N V \cong k$ if $\dim V = N$ without picking a basis. So already there are some troubles at the level of just the definition of the determinant. You certainly don't have to know the formula, but it's a bit trickier to get away with not picking a basis.